# How do I keep recalculating the batch-statistics during testing in Keras Batch Normlization layer?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, normalization, batch-normalization

I am working on a domain adaption model. From what I've understood, Keras calculates the running average of the input-data during training, but not during testin (as is described in the initial paper, nothing special so far).

Now, how can I use Keras, such that the **Batch Normalization statistics also get updated during evaluation / testing**?

More specifically:

[image: BatchNorm]

gamma and beta are learned during training time, and are kept constant during test-time.

How can I use Keras, such that my (the mean) and sigma (the stddev) are recalculated for each batch during testing?

Comment: Have you tried setting to learning phase while testing using `keras.backend.set_learning_phase(1)`? This, of course, only works as expected if batch normalization is the only phase-dependent layer in your network (e.g. using dropout would break this)

Comment: Does this backprop the gamma and beta variables though? I use dropout, but just out of curiosity this question now :)